# Azure SQL: How to Merge Multiple Db's into a Single Managing Db, while Syncing Bidirectionally any future changes

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database, azure-data-sync

I have multiple devices with assignments, where each generating similar in structure data offline. Also each device periodically gets online to sync with an Azure SQL database that is separate and only assign to it. The devices also received new assignment through syncing with the Azure SQL database.

I want to combine these multiple database into a single database for managing, while bidirectionally getting updates when a sync goes through and also relaying back any assignments to the separate databases.

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Azure SQL Data Sync for the same purpose, which can update bi-directionally and can be scheduled to run according to requirements. However for multiple databases, we need to create multiple sync groups.

[Set up SQL Data Sync between databases in Azure SQL Database and SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/sql-data-sync-sql-server-configure)

Comment: If we sync, for example the combined assignment table bi-bidirectionally, without extracting or divining the owner of the assignment, then all assignments would be equally sync to the owner and all other database/devices. Which would result a leak and large mount of unnecessary data being passed around.